# ¿Cómo sería el regex correcto para extraer el siguiente fragmento?

Tags: php, regex

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
$body = '<textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="Overview_16" style="display: inline">La serie explora lo que sucede cuando una brillante idea tecnológica cae en las manos del emprendedor equivocado. Ambientada en las calles de Miamo, la serie cuenta cómo una compañía financiada con dinero sucio proveniente de grupos criminales, tales como una banda de delincuentes haitianos, para construir un negocio estable, debe mantener sus actividades bajo secreto ante la atenta mirada del agente del FBI que tiene el poder de deshacerlo todo.

El agente del FBI Phil Rask (interpretado por Martin Freeman, Sherlock), especializado en este tipo de delitos financieros, se cruza en el camino de Nick Talman (Adam Brody The O.C.), un hombre inteligente y financista de una pequeña firma de abogados de Miami. Rask está detrás de la búsqueda del adinerado padre de Nick, con quien este tiene una relación problemática, y quien desaparece dejándole una gran cantidad de dinero de procedencia ilegal que él invierte en una \'start-up\' de tecnología. Otmara Marrero (Graceland) y Edi Gathegi (The Blacklist) también forman parte del reparto de esta serie como Izzy Morales, un genio de la tecnología que quiere cambiar el mundo, y Ronald Dacey, el segundo al mando de la banda de haitianos, respectivamente</textarea>';
```

Y quiero obtener con PHP lo que hay dentro, escribí el siguiente pattern:

```
preg_match('#<textarea rows="[^"]*" cols="[^"]*" name="Overview_16" style="display:[^"]*">(.*?)</textarea>#', $body, $sinopsis);
```

Pero al hacer `echo $sinopsis[1];` no obtengo nada. ¿Cómo debería escribir el pattern? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es simplemente que un punto (`.`) no coincide con un salto de línea `\n`. Por eso, `.*?` no va a coincidir con todo el contenido cuando tenga saltos de línea. Para que coincida, deberías usar el [modificador `s`](http://php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (*singleline* o *DOTALL*).

```
#regex#s
       ^
    El modificador /s va después del delimitador del regex
```

---

Ahora bien, estás usando regex para analizar HTML. Eso es un problema serio. En este caso te va a funcionar, pero se me ocurren muchísimos ejemplos que harían que tu expresión falle. Por ejemplo, si modificamos los atributos de la etiqueta `<textarea cols="80" rows="20">` (cambiando el orden) fallaría, y una vez que arregles eso, siempre voy a tener un ejemplo que lo haga fallar.

No deberías usar expresiones regulares para procesar HTML. Tan sólo un pequeño cambio en el HTML haría que tu regex falle. Un espacio de más, un cambio en los atributos del tag, un comentario, o estructuras más complejas, harían que hasta un regex gigantesco no siga las reglas.

Es muy sencillo procesar HTML con **[DOM](http://php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)**, son las herramientas que están pensadas para eso. En vez de tratarlo como texto, lo analizan en una estructura de nodos, como corresponde.

Simplemente se genera el DOM así:

```php
$html = 'cualquiercosa<textarea name="Overview_16">contenido de tu textarea bla bla</textarea>cualquiercosa';

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET);
```

Y podemos obtener el textarea con `name="Overview_16"`:

```php
//Obtener todos los tags <textarea> y verificar que coincida el name
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('textarea') as $textarea) 
{
    if ($textarea->getAttribute('name') == 'Overview_16') {
        $contenido = $textarea->nodeValue;
        //y lo que quieras hacer con $contenido acá
        echo 'Se encontró un textarea con name="Overview_16". Contenido:' . "\n";
        echo $contenido;
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Se encontró un textarea con name="Overview_16". Contenido:
contenido de tu textarea bla bla
```

Demo:
https://3v4l.org/UTXI0

Comment: Por eso coloqué el `[^"]*` en donde va el `cols` y `rows`

Comment: Bueno pero Mariano eso es lo de menos, podría colocar `preg_match('#<textarea [^"]* name="Overview_16" style="display:[^"]*">(.*?)</textarea>#', $body, $sinopsis);` porque el dato de columnas y filas me es irrelevante, solo quiero lo que está en medio y no puedo sacarlo :(

Comment: Quizás no leiste la primera parte de mi respuesta donde te doy la solución... Y ok, sigamos hasta que te aburras... fijate cómo falla con este caso entonces: https://regex101.com/r/4pW9AN/1 ... ¿Pensaste en usar DOM?

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano por tu paciencia, soy un poco nobato en el tema :)

Comment: De acuerdo, estaré esperando :)

Comment: @IsmaelQuirantes edité la respuesta agregando una mucho mejor solución que usar regex. Como verás, no es nada complicado usar DOM.

Comment: Wow muchas gracias de verdad, me servirá mucho estoy seguro